# How do I call a postgresql trigger function from spring jpa

Tags: spring, triggers, spring-data-jpa

I want to update my product_inventory table with a trigger. So I have a function and not a stored procedure. I want to call that function or trigger from my springboot app, maybe from the jpa repository. I don't know which one to call, the function(which returns a trigger) or trigger and how would I do that from the jpa repository. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "function which returns a trigger". In the context of databases triggers are database objects tied to tables or views that get executed (triggered, hence the name) when a SQL DML operation (insert, update, delete) affects that table. They don't get called explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications @Jens Schauder. You are right, triggers can't be called explicitly.